# Request returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tiny-tds

I have managed to connect my web service to the database, but now whenever I make a request it returns nothing. The database has a couple of rows, but the web service returns zero.

```
get '/all_users/' do
  conn = TinyTds::Client.new(username: 'nicole', password: 'pass', dataserver: 'Nikki-PC\Mydatabase', database: 'Thedatabase')
  recordsArray = "{\"clientList\":["
  clientArray = Array.new
  sql = 'select * from dbo.ServerUsers'
  records = conn.execute(sql) do |record|
    client = AndroidtableClientsSearch.new(record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4])
    clientArray << client.to_s
  end
  recordsArray << clientArray.join(',')
  recordsArray << "]}"
  recordsArray
end
```

I'm pretty sure I am doing the execute, but this is the first time I am using tiny_tds and I am very confused.
Thank you for your help.

[EDIT] 
This is AndroidClientsSearch:

```
class AndroidtableClientsSearch
   def initialize(username, password, phone_number, profile_state, clasa)
    @username = username
    @password = password
    @phone_number = phone_number
    @profile_state = profile_state
    @clasa = clasa
end

def to_s
    { :username => "#{@username}", :password => "#{@password}", :phone_number => "#{@phone_number}", :profile_state => "#{@profile_state}", :clasa =>"#{@clasa}"}.to_json
end
end
```

[UPDATE]
I have modified the code as suggested and it returns a result, but it does not return the data from the database.
This is a result:

{"recordsArray":["{\"username\":\"\",\"password\":\"\",\"phone_number\":\"\",\"profile_state\":\"\",\"clasa\":\"\"}"]}

Comment: What is `record[N]`? _Sidenote:_ building a json string by habd is a very bad idea. Create a hash and call `JSON.dump(hash)` afterwards.

Comment: my database has 5 columns and I created the class AndroidTableClientsSearch that has 5 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`conn.execute(sql)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute) does not accept a block, it simply returns a result. The proc afterwards is treated by a ruby interpreter as “orphan proc definition” and never gets executed. You might try to put `puts 'I am here'` inside it and see it is never called.

The solution would be to *iterate* the result:

```
get '/all_users/' do
  conn = TinyTds::Client.new(...)
  sql = 'select * from dbo.ServerUsers'

  #                           ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ iterate!!!
  records = conn.execute(sql).each_with_object([]) do |record, memo|
    client = AndroidtableClientsSearch.new(*5.times.map { |i| record[i] })
    memo << client.to_s
  end

  require 'json'
  JSON.dump(clientList: records)
end
```

Comment: hey, thank you for the suggestions, it really helped, but I still get an empty json as so:
"recordsArray": "{"username":"","password":"","phone_number":"","profile_state":"","clasa":""}"

Comment: Print out `record.inspect` inside iterator and you’ll get an impression on what’s going wrong.

Comment: record.inspect shows that the data is there, but it is somehow lost along the way

Comment: when i inspected client it shows that all the data becomes nil:
username = nil, password = nil, phone_number = nil, profile_state = nil, clasa = nil

Comment: I've fixed it :) thank you very much for the help and the suggestions. You saved my life. Thank you again